# How to avoid google map path direction overlaps the last one while showing the updated location?

Tags: java, android, google-maps

In my Android project, I am showing one google map which includes my location as origin and my friends locations as destination. 
As, the location data are saved in firebase. With the real time change in the location, I recall the API to show the update in the map.

**But the problem is-**
While showing the update in the map, it shows the updated path direction with previous one. So, all the paths are overlapped with the previous ones. But I want to regenerate the map according to the updated location.

Here's the output it shows, when the location is updated, the Marker A in the picture is my location and after update, it generates the new marker A with the previous one.

[image]

I have cleared all the originMarker, destinationMarker and polylinePaths lists. But still not working.

Here's the code of my **MapActivity.js**

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, DirectionFinderListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

        final Intent intent = getIntent();
        myLat = intent.getStringExtra("my_lat");
        myLong = intent.getStringExtra("my_long");

        //saving to database starts
        users = new ArrayList<>();
        friends = new ArrayList<>();
        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users");
        //saving to database ends

        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        btnFindPath = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnFindPath);
        etOrigin = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etOrigin);
        etDestination = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etDestination);

    }


    private void sendRequest() {
        originMarkers.clear();
        destinationMarkers.clear();
        polylinePaths.clear();

        for(int i = 0; i < users.size(); i++) {
            if(users.get(i).getEmail().equals(userEmail)) {
                origin = users.get(i).getLatitude()+","+users.get(i).getLongitude();
            }
        }

        String destination = etDestination.getText().toString();

        try {
            new DirectionFinder(this, origin, address).execute();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

        try {

            databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    users.clear();
                    polylinePaths.clear();
                    originMarkers.clear();
                    destinationMarkers.clear();

                    for(DataSnapshot postSnapShot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        User user = postSnapShot.getValue(User.class);
                        users.add(user);
                    }

                    for(int i = 0; i < users.size(); i++) {

                        if(users.get(i).getEmail().equals(userEmail) ) {
                            myLat = users.get(i).getLatitude();
                            myLong = users.get(i).getLongitude();
                        }
                    }
                    sendRequest();
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }

        mMap = googleMap;
        LatLng hcmus = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(myLat),  Double.parseDouble(myLong));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(hcmus, 18));
        originMarkers.add(mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .title("My Location")
                .position(hcmus)));

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    }


    @Override
    public void onDirectionFinderStart() {

        try {
            progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Please wait.",
                    "Finding direction..!", true);
            progressDialog.setCancelable(true);

            if (originMarkers != null) {
                for (Marker marker : originMarkers) {
                    marker.remove();
                }
            }

            if (destinationMarkers != null) {
                for (Marker marker : destinationMarkers) {
                    marker.remove();
                }
            }

            if (polylinePaths != null) {
                for (Polyline polyline:polylinePaths ) {
                    polyline.remove();
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onDirectionFinderSuccess(List<Route> routes) {

        progressDialog.dismiss();
        polylinePaths = new ArrayList<>();
        originMarkers = new ArrayList<>();
        destinationMarkers = new ArrayList<>();

        originMarkers.clear();
        destinationMarkers.clear();
        polylinePaths.clear();

        for (Route route : routes) {
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(route.startLocation, 16));
            ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDuration)).setText(route.duration.text);
            ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDistance)).setText(route.distance.text);

            originMarkers.add(mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.start_blue))
                    .title(route.startAddress)
                    .position(route.startLocation)));
            destinationMarkers.add(mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.end_green))
                    .title(route.endAddress)
                    .position(route.endLocation)));

            PolylineOptions polylineOptions = new PolylineOptions().
                    geodesic(true).
                    color(Color.BLUE).
                    width(10);

            for (int i = 0; i < route.points.size(); i++)
                polylineOptions.add(route.points.get(i));

            polylinePaths.add(mMap.addPolyline(polylineOptions));
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        try {

            databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    users.clear();
                    address.clear();
                    polylinePaths.clear();
                    originMarkers.clear();
                    destinationMarkers.clear();

                    for(DataSnapshot postSnapShot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        User user = postSnapShot.getValue(User.class);
                        users.add(user);
                    }

                    for(int i = 0; i < users.size(); i++) {

                                if(users.get(i).getLatitude() != null && users.get(i).getLongitude()!= null) {
                                    address.add(users.get(i).getLatitude()+","+users.get(i).getLongitude());
                                }

                    }

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }

    }

}
```

And here is the code to do the API call section and getting the direction to draw in map-

**DirectionFinder.java**

```
public class DirectionFinder {
    private static final String DIRECTION_URL_API = "direction API url";
    private static final String GOOGLE_API_KEY = "my API key";
    private DirectionFinderListener listener;
    private String origin;
    private ArrayList<String> destination;


    public DirectionFinder(DirectionFinderListener listener, String origin, ArrayList<String> destination) {
        this.listener = listener;
        this.origin = origin;
        this.destination = destination;
    }

    public void execute() throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        listener.onDirectionFinderStart();

        for(int i=0;i<destination.size();i++)
            new DownloadRawData().execute(createUrl(destination.get(i)));
    }

    private String createUrl(String des) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        String urlOrigin = URLEncoder.encode(origin, "utf-8");

        String urlDestination = URLEncoder.encode(des, "utf-8");

        Log.e("#LOCATION_PATH:", DIRECTION_URL_API + "origin=" + urlOrigin + "&destination=" + urlDestination +"&alternatives=true&key=" + GOOGLE_API_KEY);

        return DIRECTION_URL_API + "origin=" + urlOrigin + "&destination=" + urlDestination + "&alternatives=true&key=" + GOOGLE_API_KEY;
    }

    private class DownloadRawData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            String link = params[0];
            try {
                URL url = new URL(link);
                InputStream is = url.openConnection().getInputStream();
                StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    buffer.append(line + "\n");
                }

                return buffer.toString();

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String res) {
            try {
                parseJSon(res);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private void parseJSon(String data) throws JSONException {
        if (data == null)
            return;

        List<Route> routes = new ArrayList<Route>();
        JSONObject jsonData = new JSONObject(data);
        JSONArray jsonRoutes = jsonData.getJSONArray("routes");
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonRoutes.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jsonRoute = jsonRoutes.getJSONObject(i);
            Route route = new Route();

            JSONObject overview_polylineJson = jsonRoute.getJSONObject("overview_polyline");
            JSONArray jsonLegs = jsonRoute.getJSONArray("legs");
            JSONObject jsonLeg = jsonLegs.getJSONObject(0);
            JSONObject jsonDistance = jsonLeg.getJSONObject("distance");
            JSONObject jsonDuration = jsonLeg.getJSONObject("duration");
            JSONObject jsonEndLocation = jsonLeg.getJSONObject("end_location");
            JSONObject jsonStartLocation = jsonLeg.getJSONObject("start_location");

            route.distance = new Distance(jsonDistance.getString("text"), jsonDistance.getInt("value"));
            route.duration = new Duration(jsonDuration.getString("text"), jsonDuration.getInt("value"));
            route.endAddress = jsonLeg.getString("end_address");
            route.startAddress = jsonLeg.getString("start_address");
            route.startLocation = new LatLng(jsonStartLocation.getDouble("lat"), jsonStartLocation.getDouble("lng"));
            route.endLocation = new LatLng(jsonEndLocation.getDouble("lat"), jsonEndLocation.getDouble("lng"));
            route.points = decodePolyLine(overview_polylineJson.getString("points"));

            routes.add(route);
        }

        listener.onDirectionFinderSuccess(routes);
    }

    private List<LatLng> decodePolyLine(final String poly) {
        int len = poly.length();
        int index = 0;
        List<LatLng> decoded = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
        int lat = 0;
        int lng = 0;

        while (index < len) {
            int b;
            int shift = 0;
            int result = 0;
            do {
                b = poly.charAt(index++) - 63;
                result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
                shift += 5;
            } while (b >= 0x20);
            int dlat = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
            lat += dlat;

            shift = 0;
            result = 0;
            do {
                b = poly.charAt(index++) - 63;
                result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
                shift += 5;
            } while (b >= 0x20);
            int dlng = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
            lng += dlng;

            decoded.add(new LatLng(
                    lat / 100000d, lng / 100000d
            ));
        }

        return decoded;
    }
}
```

So, I need a solution to solve the rewriting the map issue and showing only one direction path from my origin to destination. It would be very nice if someone help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Whenever data changes `onDataChange` the first thing that is done is `polylinePaths.clear()`.  This prevents the code in `onDirectionFinderStart` from clearing the previous polylines since the array is empty.   Clear the `polylinePaths` after the remove loop.